# UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad for currency field in 4.3 iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uikeyboardtype

I am not able to successfully use `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` when i run on simulator 4.3 and it successfully works on simulator 5.0. I have currency to be filled in textfield.

How can i use `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` for device running 4.3 ?

**Edited**
in simulator 4.3 it is giving following warning:
"Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using Default"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simulator autocorrection was called which crashed my app..
it is Lion 10.7.2 + Xcode 4.2 + Simulator running iOS 4.3 problem

Now solution to it is

We have to update Simulator 4.3 , by following this steps: 1) Go to Xcode->Preferences->Download 2) Update iOS 4.3 Simulator

And Reset Simulator ,and run it again... its done...

Comment: For me it works in the simulator and not the Ipad. Just dont get that.

Comment: try to on/off auto-correction from general settings in setting app of iPad. check if off auto correction works for you

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a warning because i am using IOS 4.3 and it's printing that error in Logs and working perfectly.I am using following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  myTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
}
```

Comment: Yes its warning.  i will edit my question. Actually when i use simulator 5.0 and edit currency textfield application runs smoothly and in simulator 4.3 it crash without any error with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on main.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are releasing a variable before completion of it's scope means variable is used in code after releasing.So just remove release statement and replace it with nil assignment...i hope your problem will be solved..